Show that $E [ \int_s^t W_u \, du \,|\, \mathcal{F}_s ] = (t - s) W_s$
Show that
$$E \left[ \int_s^t W_u \, du \,|\, \mathcal{F}_s \right] = (t - s) W_s$$
where $W_u$ is a standard Brownian motion and $\mathcal{F}_s$ is the filtration up to time $s $.

I prefer to use integration by parts and write
$$
\int_s^tW_{\color{red}u}\,d\color{red}u=tW_t-sW_s-\int_s^tu\,dW_u\,.
$$
Then, by the martingale property of $W_t$ and the $dW_u$-integral,
$$
\mathbb E\left[\int_s^tW_u\,du\, \Bigg|\,{\cal F}_s\right]=tW_s-sW_s-0\,.
$$

Given that the expectation of a Wiener process is a martingale (the value of the Wiener process in the next period $t$ has the same value as the current $s$) and if you plot the value of the Wiener process against time, your integral evaluates to give us the "area of a rectangle", which is $(t-s)W_s$
Please let me know if you need more details.

thanks for the intuition! also, from another point of view the solution could be seen as: $E \left[ \int_s^t W_s , ds \Bigg| \mathcal{F}_s \right] = W_s \int_s^t du= (t - s) W_s$ as $W_s$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$ measurable? thanks!

That does make sense, but I'm not exactly sure if its mathematically sound. Maybe some of the math-experts here can chip in.

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_s^t W_u \, du \, \middle| \, \mathcal{F}_s \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[\int_s^t (W_u - W_s + W_s) \, du \, \middle| \, \mathcal{F}_s \right]
= \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left[\int_s^t (W_u - W_s) \, du \, \middle| \, \mathcal{F}_s \right]}_{1)} 
+ \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left[\int_s^t W_s \, du \, \middle| \, \mathcal{F}_s \right]}_{2)}
= (t - s) W_s
$$
1) $$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_s^t (W_u - W_s) \, du \, \middle| \, \mathcal{F}_s \right] 
= \int_s^t \mathbb{E}(W_u - W_s) \, du = 0, \quad \text{since } W_u - W_s \text{ is independent from } \mathcal{F}_s.
$$
2)
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_s^t W_s \, du \, \middle| \, \mathcal{F}_s \right] 
= W_s \int_s^t du = W_s (t - s).
$$
